# How can I perform an XPath selection on an XElement that was extracted from a larger XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

Suppose I load an XML document into memory and extract one of the elements inside. For example:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<A><B><C/></B><D/></A>");
XElement b = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "B").Single();
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

This results in `<B><C/></B>` returned, so I have an XElement that represents a small part of the original XML document.

I'd now like to perform an XPath selection on just that part I've extracted. However, experimenting with XPathSelectElement/s tells me that all my XPath expressions are operating on the original XML document.

`b.XPathSelectElement("/A")` returns the original document's root element.
`b.XPathSelectElement("/B")` returns null.
`b.XPathSelectElement("/")` throws an exception, "The XPath expression evaluated to unexpected type System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.".

How can I perform XPath selections on only an XElement's contents?
(Hopefully without converting to a string and re-parsing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you make a copy or clone of the XML structure, you can simply use a path relative to the context node like

```
b.XPathSelectElement("C")
```

This should return the `<C />` element.
The `/` axis always selects the document node of the XML.